# Reduce this equation to first order: $y''+y=\frac12\cosh(y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Equation is

$$y''+y=\frac{1}{2}\cosh(y)  $$
$ y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=\sqrt{0.3}$

What is the max value of y?

Need help for my revision for exam. thank you.

Comment: Where have you started? What exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: y''+y = y' (d'y/dy) + y ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with $2y'$ and integrate once to get
$$
y'^2+y^2=\sinh(y)+C
$$
where you find from initial conditions that $C=0.3$.

---

The maximal value of $y$ is taken at one of the places where $y'=0$ so that you have to solve
$$
y^2=\sinh(y)+0.3
$$

[image]

In the graph one can see that there are roots close to $-0.25$, $1.8$ and $2.4$. The solution of the ODE however can only move below the zero level as $y'^2$ is non-negative. Thus the max of the solution to the given IVP will have its maximum at $1.8$

Comment: Wouldn't the term $sinh(y)$ be squared too?

Comment: No, why? $\int \cosh(y)y'dt=\int \cosh(y)dy$.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad. I thought you square the equation. But you mentioned to integrate it.

Comment: How do you solve sinh(y)? It's my first time with hyperbolic functions..

Comment: You can only find numerical solutions. For a first estimate replace $\sinh y$ by its linearization $y$, so that $(y-0.5)^2=0.55$, $y=0.5\pm \sqrt{0.55}$.

Comment: But the answer is max y is 1.8. I am not sure how to obtain that answer.

Comment: Yes, the sinh graph is much more curved in the critical area and follows the parabola $y^2-0.3$ more closely so that the intersection is well above the estimated $1.2$. However, that was only meant as a first overview. As sinh grows exponentially, there is also a third intersection point.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Let $s=y’$.

This yields:
$$s\frac{ds}{dy}=\frac1{2}\cosh y-y$$

---

$$sds=\left(\frac1{2}\cosh y-y\right)dy$$

$$C_1+\frac{s^2}2=-\frac{y^2}2+\frac{\sinh y}2$$

Clearly, $C_1=-0.15$.

---

The max value $y$ can attain, should occur at $s=0$.

Thus, the maximum value of $y$, call it $M$, satisfies

$$\frac{\sinh M-M^2}2=-0.15$$

and
$$y’’=\frac{\cosh M}2-M<0$$

Numerically, $M\approx 1.8$.

Comment: $$y'' = s\frac{ds}{dy}$$

Comment: @happywand yes it is.

Comment: integrate $y′′=s\frac{ds}{dy}$ and $\frac{1}{2}cosh(y) + y$

Comment: @happywand with respect to $y$.

Comment: $y' = \frac{1}{2}sinh(y) + \frac{1}{2}y^2$

Comment: @happywand See my edited answer.

Comment: what would the max value of y be?

Comment: @happywand see my edited answer.

Comment: I do not understand how you solve the first eqn..

Comment: The second eqn is to show it is approaching a maximum point right?

Comment: @happywand The first equation can only be solved numerically. And, yes, the second equation shows the tendency to a local maximim.

Comment: Thank you for your help!